# Как получить первый попавшийся ключ по подходящему значению многомерного массива у которого все индексы цифровые?

Tags: php

Допустим есть вот такой массив

```
[ 1, 2, [ 1, 2, [ 1, 2, 3 ], 4, 5 ], 4, 5 ]
```

Мне нужно получит первый попавшийся (любой) ключ у которого значение например равно `3` (трем).

Comment: А если значение найдется во вложенном массиве, какой ключ надо вернуть?

Comment: полный начиная от начала

Comment: задача на реализацию простейшей рекурсии. в чем проблема то у вас?

Comment: @teran а готовой функции для этого не существует?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно получить именно массив соответствующей структуры:

```
$arr = [ 1, 2, [ 1, 2, [ 1, 2, 3 ], 4, 5 ], 4, 5 ];

print_r( foo($arr, 3) );


function foo(Array $arr, $need) {
    static $triger = true;
    $result = [];

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if ( is_array($val) && !empty($tmp = foo($val, $need)) ) {
            $result[$key] = $tmp;
        }

        if ($val == $need & $triger) {
            $result[$key] = $val;
            $triger = false;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: вы нашли индекс третьего вложенного массива а не полный ключ. должно быть arr[2][2][2]

Comment: @perfect отредактировал ответ.

Comment: нет нужен ключ, а не массив

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [ 1, 2, [ 1, 2, [ 1, 2, 3 ], 4, 5 ], 4, 5 ];

function recu($arr, $oldKey = "") {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == 3)
                echo "finded in position ".$oldKey."_".$key."_";

        if (is_array($value))
            return recu($value, "".$oldKey."_".$key."_");
    }
}

recu($arr);
```